# Add incremental counter in array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows

```
    data = [
    {
     sNo:1,
     month:[
     {
      id:1,
      value:0
     },
     {
      id:5,
      value:10
     }]
    },
     {
     sNo:2,
     month:[
     {
      id:6,
      value:10
     },
     {
      id:9,
      value:20
     }]
     }
    ]
```

I want to add an incremental counter in month array such that count keeps increasing till last element. So my final array looks like this

```
    data = [
    {
     sNo:1,
     month:[
     {
      id:1,
      value:0
      count:1
     },
     {
      id:5,
      value:10,
      count:2
     }]
    },
     {
     sNo:2,
     month:[
     {
      id:6,
      value:10,
      count:3
     },
     {
      id:9,
      value:20,
      count:4
     }]
     }
    ]
```

Here count is increasing regardless of element. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can :

- define count outside the array treatment
- and use array.map to add the new colum on each month

```js
const data = [{
    sNo: 1,
    month: [{
        id: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        value: 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    sNo: 2,
    month: [{
        id: 6,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        value: 20
      }
    ]
  }
];

let count = 0;
const result = data.map(one => ({ ...one,
  month: one.month.map(month => ({
    ...month,
    count: ++count
  }))
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of `.forEach` to achieve this. Try this

```js
let data = [{sNo:1, month:[{id:1, value:0 }, {id:5, value:10 }] }, {sNo:2, month:[{id:6, value:10 }, {id:9, value:20 }] } ];

let index = 1;
data.forEach(obj => {
    obj.month.forEach(m => m.count = index++);
});

console.log(data);
```